# Can I delete Org Administrators from ApigeeApp Services

Tags: apigee

I've added someone to my App Services Org as an Org admin (not a user in an app). How do I delete them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:

`curl -X DELETE https://api.usergrid.com/management/orgs/{org_id}/users/{user_id} -H 'Authorization: Bearer yourTokenLJKhukhkjKUHkhkjhk'`

Comment: Cool -- no way to do this via the UI though, correct?

Comment: Thanks, Diego.  BTW, easiest way to get a token is to open up dev tools for your browser and open any page in App Services.  There will be a series of API calls that have a query parameter called `access_token` and you can just use that for a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the user roles thru UI by selecting the organization user under Admin tab.

Answer (score -1):

If deleting from multiple orgs, using BSD/*nix/Mac OS X, and using [resty](https://github.com/micha/resty), try the following:

```
[user@host ~]$ source ~/bin/resty; resty http://api.enterprise.apigee.com:8080/v1 -u ${USERID}:${PASSWORD} -H 'Accept: application/json'; GET /users/**username**/userroles | grep "organization"| awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\"" } ; { print $4 }' > /tmp/my_orgadmin_orgs.lst

[user@host ~]$ for eachOrg in $(cat /tmp/my_orgadmin_orgs.lst); do DELETE /o/${eachOrg}/userroles/orgadmin/users/**username** -v; done
```

Comment: App Services has separate org user management.  You're describing API Services (Apigee Gateway)

Comment: Correct, apologies for the confusion, although the same concept applies for App Services.  With some minor modifications, the above would serve the same need for multiple orgadmins.